# For etl, where can I download data in order to construct data warehouse

Tags: database, data-warehouse

I am using jaspersoft etl tools. But, to construct data warehouse, I need sample data. Where can I find a sample data to process them in etl tools to construct a data warehouse ?

Answer (score 1):

You can have fun with the stackoverflow data for example: https://api.stackexchange.com/